# Create entry in Access form based on entry chosen from combox box (without including the entry from the combo box)

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I use Access to maintain a list (with details) of cases I work on (I am a legal professional). I want Access to add an unique case identifier to every case. I use a form to enter the data in the database.

I wrote this very simple code to add the Case ID nr:

```
Private Sub Command81_Click()
If Not IsNull(Me.Case_ID) Then
DoCmd.CancelEvent
Else
Command81.Enabled = True
Me.Case_ID = Me.Combo321 + Format(Me.[Date Original Event], "yymmdd") + Format(Time, "hhmmss")
End If
End Sub
```

The idea is I fill the different fields in the form and then click a button to add the case ID (listed in the textbox (in the form) and field (in the database) called 'Case_ID').

When I click the button it should check whether there is already a case ID. If there is it will not create a new one. If there is none a new case ID will be created based on the country where the case happened (Combo321) + the date when the original event happened + time I created the case ID.

The country where the case happened is choosen from a dropdown menu (Combo321). The options in the dropdown menu come from a table with a list of countries:

The Netherlands, United Kingdom, Germany, etc.

If possible I want to keep the list of (full) country names in the dropdown menu, but in the case ID use a 2 or 3 character abbreviation. So if I choose from the dropdown menu that the case happened in The Netherlands I would like the case nr to start with NL, if the case happened in the United Kingdom I would like the case Nr to start with UK, etc.

Is it possible in the table with the country names to make a second column with the abbreviations and then in the code somehow to have the case ID start with the entry in that 2nd column that 'belongs' to the relevant entry in the first column (the full country name) that I picked from the dropdown menu?

Or maybe there is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create field in table. Then have that field in combobox RowSource (multi-column combobox). Combobox properties:

RowSource: `SELECT CountryCode, Country FROM Countries;`
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 0";1.0"
BoundColumn: 1
ControlSource: field to save selected combobox value

Two-letter CountryCode will be saved into record if combobox is bound to field. It will also be used by your code.

Saving data dependent on other data is usually not necessary and often a bad idea. This identifier can be constructed by expression when needed for display.

Also, advise to develop habit of using `nn` for minutes instead of `mm`. It actually doesn't seem to make a difference in Format() function but I have seen usage where it does, although can't recall exact circumstances.